# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts when I just start to configure

Tags: mysql, sql

I was starting to learning SQL, then I download MySQL, but I am stuck in this error, I retry again and again but it didn't work still.

[image: (1) screenshot i took from that installment]

[image: (2) screenshot i took from that installment]

```
Beginning configuration step: Starting the server

Attempting to start service MySQL80...
Successfully started service MySQL80.
Waiting until a connection to MySQL Server 8.0.18 can be established (with a maximum of 10 attempts)...
Retry 1: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3305 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 2: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 3: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3305 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 4: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 5: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3305 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 6: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 7: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3305 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 8: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 9: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3305 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 10: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Failed to connect to MySQL Server 8.0.18 after 10 attempts.
Ended configuration step: Starting the server
```

Comment: The fact that you're trying to connect as `root` without a password is a concern unto itself.

Comment: I can't do anything, I'm just follow the procedure

Comment: It was the **without a password** that I was talking about.

Comment: the 8.018 Server is a bad update. When i installed it it also didn't start. Then i changed to services, and stqartet it manually. it gave an error message but it had started anyway..

Comment: How to do it manually @nbk

Comment: start services.msc from comand prompt or enter services into windows search

Answer (score 1):

I was face same problem when it come to step starting the server it make error!
Based on my experience This is caused by the antivirus program, after I disabled the Antivirus, the installation was completed without problems.